# Where is Git: Add Remote command?

Tags: visual-studio-code

As you can see in [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_46#_add-remote-from-github) a command named `Git: Add Remote...` has been added to vs code and as you can see in [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_48) and [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_47), it haven't been removed. So, why I can't find it?
(I am very very noob at using git)

[image: Command Not Found]

edit:
I found it in keyboard shortcuts.
[image: Found in Keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Note that this is strictly an IDE matter: it has nothing to do with Git itself, nor with GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure that the folder you opened up in VS Code has a git repository initialized.

You can check if your folder is a git repository with `git status` for example.
Or `ls -alt` lists all files in the folder. Check for a .git folder. If there is none, your folder is not a git repository.

- Create a git repository with `git init`
- Add a remote to master branch with `git add remote <NAME> <URL>`
- Replace `<NAME>` with remote name and `<URL>` with URL from where to fetch/push remote. For example `git add remote origin https://github.com/user/repo.git`

Comment: Here is the response: `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`  What to do next?

Comment: Open the folder where your code lives in VS Code. On your screenshot, there is no folder opened. Then create a git repository. From the terminal with `git init` then you have a master branch. Now, it should be possible to add a remote. I usually work with git from the command line, not with VS code features. So I am not so familiar with that.

Comment: Or try `Git: Initialize Repository` in your main folder. Like in your first screenshot

Comment: Here Githubs description of how to add a remote to an existing repository. https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/adding-a-remote